# Optimal way to write 2d array into unformatted file using nested implicit loops

Tags: io, fortran

I have a piece of code writing a 2D array `var` into a fortran unformatted file.
I'd prefer it to be written line-by-line. I therefore need to loop in an non-optimal order fortran-wise, because it is recommended to loop on the outer dimension first.

```
write(fileid, pos = pos) ((var(i,j),j=1,size(var,2)),i=1,size(var,1))
```

I'm wondering whether transposing the way I write into the file would be more optimal, or whether this is not necessary because the I/O process should be dominating over the cache/memory access in this situation.

Comment: What did your measurements show?

Comment: I didn' t do any measurements as I thought there might be a generic answer to this question. But if you tell me there's not any generic answer, then I'll perform some tests and let the community know, with a decent descriptionon my benchmark, of course.

Comment: We have caches and buffers of various sizes and data of various sizes. We have hard discs, SSD discs, we have discs on the same device, discs accessed over some interconnection, over ethernet... It is hard to assume a generic answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a retired Fortran compiler and I/O library developer, and my experience here is that you would be far better off to write the whole array. Using implied loops as you have it, out of memory order, will typically require each element to be transmitted separately to the I/O library, with lots of processing overhead per element. Writing the whole array can result in a single I/O transfer directly from your array.

Given that you are using unformatted I/O, I don't understand the desire to write a row at a time, unless this is going to be read by some other software.

Comment: That's definitely helpful. The reason why I need to write row-by-row is precisely because I need the file as input for a different non-fortran software.

Comment: You may want to consider changing the Fortran declaration of the array to reflect the desired storage order. A lot will depend on how your Fortran code accesses the array. But unless you have found performance to be a problem, just write the code in the way that makes the most sense to you and don't worry about it. You MIGHT want to consider (var(i,:),i=1,size(var,1)) as this might give the possibility of some optimization.